# Gradle exec block not using passed environment

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to use npm to build some projects. In jenkins there are various node versions installed but I need to use a specific version of npm to build my project. I am passing the environement with 'PATH' variable value in exec block but it is not picking that path.

```
def pathEnvironment = [:]
    pathEnvironment["PATH"] = "/scratch/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/bin:" + System.getenv("PATH")

    exec {
        environment = pathEnvironment
        workingDir workspaceLocation
        commandLine "npm", "install"
    }
```

```
exec {
        environment "PATH", "/scratch/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/bin:" + System.getenv("PATH")
        workingDir workspaceLocation
        commandLine "npm", "install"
    }
```

[image]

I am getting error shown in above image.

I am using jenkins gradle plugin with gradle version 5.4.1.

What needs to be done to be able to set the path for the exec block?